# Configuring session on windows azure

Tags: session, azure-storage

I m using the local system to test session on windows azure. I have done the following config in web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- account configuration -->
    <add key="TableStorageEndpoint" value="http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/" />
    <add key="BlobStorageEndpoint" value="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/" />
    <add key="AccountName" value="devstoreaccount1" />
    <add key="AccountSharedKey" value="Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==" />
    <add key="DefaultMembershipTableName" value="Membership" />
    <add key="DefaultRoleTableName" value="Roles" />
    <add key="DefaultSessionTableName" value="Sessions" />
    <add key="DefaultProviderApplicationName" value="ProviderTest" />
    <add key="DefaultProfileContainerName" />
    <add key="DefaultSessionContainerName" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>

    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="TableStorageSessionStateProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="TableStorageSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.AspProviders.TableStorageSessionStateProvider" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

but now i an getting the following error

> Configuration Error Description: An
>   error occurred during the processing
>   of a configuration file required to
>   service this request. Please review
>   the specific error details below and
>   modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 39:        Line 40:
>    Line 41:          Line 42:        Line
>   43:
>
> Source File:
>   C:\Users\GizaKarthik\Desktop\SessionDemo\SessionDemo\SessionDemo_WebRole\web.config
>   Line: 41
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following
>   information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could
>   not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is
>   turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with
>   assembly bind failure logging. To turn
>   this feature off, remove the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the exeption is that i used a corrupted dll. Download the additional c# examples from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazuresamples) . Find asp provides project edit the code in TableStorageSessionstateProvider

find this code

```
            else            
            {     
                    byte[] items = Convert.FromBase64String(reader.ReadLine());
                    byte[] statics = Convert.FromBase64String(reader.ReadLine());
                    int timeout = session.Timeout;
                    // Deserialize the session
                    result = DeserializeSession(items, statics, timeout);

            }
```

replace the above code with this

```
            else
            {
                try // Added try statement   
                {
                    // Read Items, StaticObjects, and Timeout from the file
                    byte[] items = Convert.FromBase64String(reader.ReadLine());
                    byte[] statics = Convert.FromBase64String(reader.ReadLine());
                    int timeout = session.Timeout;
                    // Deserialize the session
                    result = DeserializeSession(items, statics, timeout);
                }
                catch (Exception e) // Added catch statement
                {
                    // Return an empty SessionStateStoreData   
                    result = new SessionStateStoreData(new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                                       SessionStateUtility.GetSessionStaticObjects(context),
                                                       session.Timeout);
                }

            }
```

Then compile and use the dll. It should work like a champ. happy coding!!